# Java Play 2.1RC2: submitting a form: bindFromRequest() not working, request().body() is null

Tags: playframework-2.1

I'm trying to submit a User form in Play 2.1 RC2.

here is users.scala.html, which displays the user form:

```
@(users: List[User], userForm: Form[User], isReadOnly: Boolean)

@import helper._
@import security._

@helper.form(action = routes.Users.updateOrCreate(), 'id->"User_Form"){

@*Variable inputs*@
@if(users == null) {
  @*name field for Users.create, update, and read*@
  @input(userForm("username"), '_showConstraints-> true, '_label->"User: ", 'class->"selector", '_id->"username", 'name->"username", 'id->"username"){ (id, name, value, args) => <input type="text" @if(isReadOnly){readonly}>}
  } else{@if(users!=null && userForm("id")==null){
  @*name field for Users.fillFrom and Users.all*@
    @if(users.size < 15){
      <div id = User_username-select>
          <label for="username">User: </label>
          <select name="username" id="username" form=@userForm</select>
      </div>
    }else{
      @inputText(userForm("username"), '_id->"username", 'class->"selector", '_showConstraints->false, '_label->"User: ")        } 
}else{@*this has been reached if no name field of any sort displays*@}}

@*non-variable fields*@

@input(userForm("password"), '_id->"User_password", '_showConstraints-> true, '_label->"Password: "){ (id, name, value, args) => <input type="password" @if(isReadOnly){readonly}>}

@input(userForm("name"), '_id->"User_name", '_showConstraints-> true, '_label->"Name: ", 'readonly->isReadOnly){ (id, name, value, args) => <input type="text" @if(isReadOnly){readonly}>}

@input(userForm("role"), '_showConstraints-> true){ (id, name, value, args) => <input type="text" @if(isReadOnly){readonly}>}  

<input type="submit" value="submit">

}
```

The line of the routes file that it follows is `POST         /models/User/updateOrCreate                                 controllers.Users.updateOrCreate()` which leads it to this method in the Users controller:

```
public static Result updateOrCreate(){
    //check form for errors
    Form<User> filledForm = userForm.bindFromRequest(); 

    System.out.println("INSIDE UPDATEORCREATE: ");
    System.out.println(request().body().asText());
    System.out.println(userForm.data());
    System.out.println(filledForm.data());

    if(filledForm.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println(filledForm.errors());
        return badRequest(users.render(null, filledForm, false));
    }
    //saves the User and returns a string containing the id
    //return redirect(routes.Users.read(User.updateOrCreate(filledForm.get())));
    return ok(users.render(null, filledForm, false));
}
```

The printlns in the controller method, however, print "null", "{}", and "{}", respectively. I have commented out all validation in the model, so the problem isn't failed validation; for some reason, the data in the form is never being submitted in the request.

Comment: have you tried `filledForm.field("name").valueOr("Nothing")` ?